# Unity 3D rotate an object inside another object without affect both

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object named `ObjectA`, this is a 2D component, as property of this object I have a `TextMesh`.

```
public class Bubble : MonoBehaviour {
    public TextMesh text;

    void Start(){
          Game.game.objectA.Add(this);
        var textMesh = gameObject.AddComponent<TextMesh> ();
        text = textMesh;
        text.text = "Hello world";
        text.transform.Rotate(73, 305, 307);
    }
}
```

Well, the problem is, both components, the `objectA` cloned and the property `text` are added correctly in the scene, but the `objectA` has the same rotation of his property.

How I can implement different rotation for both components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a logic Error. If you check your Flow carefully. You are trying to Add
`ObjectA` So this ObjectA already have a Component Field that is null at the beginning **spoiler alert, not a child** Then you created a TextMesh Component.

Then assign the `text` field pointer to it. *why don't you just directly add it into the `text` pointer then*.

Lastly you Rotate the Component TextMesh, which is a part of the ObjectA. This will Rotate the ObjectA as well, because they are as **ONE** gameObject. So what you need to do is make 2 Different object and make the other a child with the TextMesh component. Always remember that

> Component transform, is the same as the GameObject Transform. Every GameObject needs to have a transform component, BUT ONLY ONE.

Hope this explains your problem.